# How to access network id in asp.net 4.0

Tags: .net, authentication, windows-authentication, asp.net-4.0

I have created a test web application in .Net framework 4.0 with Default.aspx page. I just want o access network id of user so I wrote following code in default.aspx code behind but getting blank value when I run the application pressing F5:

```
string username = Page.User.Identity.Name;
```

and in web.config enable the Windows authentication mode:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

then I tried following in Console application and I'm able to get my network id:

```
Console.WriteLine(Environment.UserName);
```

Am I missing any configuration steps in web application.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is production code that I use that will get the user information and also check AD groups too.

create a variable that will initialise the class and access whichever method you need which will return you your AD \ Network information.

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using System.Security.Principal;

public class IsUserInRole
{

public static bool IsInGroup(string groupName)
{
    var myIdentity = GetUserIdWithDomain();
    var myPrincipal = new WindowsPrincipal(myIdentity);
    return myPrincipal.IsInRole(groupName);
}


public bool IsInGroup(List<string> groupNames)
{
    var myIdentity = GetUserIdWithDomain();
    var myPrincipal = new WindowsPrincipal(myIdentity);

    if (groupNames.Any(@group => myPrincipal.IsInRole(@group) == true))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}

public static WindowsIdentity GetUserIdWithDomain()
{
    WindowsIdentity myIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
    return myIdentity;
}

public static string GetUserId()
{
    var id = GetUserIdWithDomain().Name.ToString().Split("\\");
    return id(1);
}


public static string GetUserDisplayName()
{
    var id = GetUserIdWithDomain().Name.ToString().Split("\\");

    var dc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, id(0));
    var adUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(dc, id(1));
    return adUser.DisplayName;

}


}
```

Edit 1

Gven your comments re the user its returning you need to add the following to your web.config file

```
  <system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true" />
   ...
  </system.web>
```

And then also in IIS go to your site \ Application then go to Authorization, then disable Anonymous User, Enable ASP.Net Impersonation and Windows Authentication

[image]

Edit 2

When you're challenged for access this means you don't have the right permissions set

Comment: I wrote following line in Page_Load event

'Response.Write("Username: "+ WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);' and hosted website in IIS. I got following message in page:
Username: IIS APPPOOL\TestWeb
Instead it should display my domainname and network id for example
Username: mydomain\mynetowrkid

Comment: ok, and what did that give you? Also whats your IIS setup re Authentication of your users on the site.

Comment: after this to get Windows Authentication I did following in IIS

Anonymous Authentication Disabled
ASP.NET Impersonation Disabled
Forms Authentication Disabled
Windows Authentication Enabled

and in web.config  <authentication mode="Windows" />

Now if I browse the website I got Windows Security pop up and ask my windows credentials. I tried with my windows login details but go following message:

Username: mydomain\mynetworkid
Password: my windows password

HTTP Error 401.1 - Unauthorized

Comment: where is your web application being held on the server? Does your use have permissions to that folder \ area?

Comment: @Sukhi just reading your comments again you need Impersonation Enabled

Comment: I did all that above settings and I got Windows Security pop up and ask my windows credentials and again I got same error HTTP Error 401.1 - Unauthorized
Where should I check for right permission

Comment: I did enable only Basic Authentication and now I am able to login with my windows credentials

Comment: Later on I did enable only Windows Authentication and added new binding( for exp: 192.168.1.14 and port 83). I browsed  http://192.168.1.14:83 URL from other computer on same network and able to login with windows credentials.

Comment: sorry just seen your responses, which version of IIS are you working on?  if its IIS 7 or above then you need to click on your site \ application. then Go to the authorisation icon, double click this and then set your options there.

Comment: I am happy to work through this with you in a chat so that i can direct you exactly where you need to go